# Jquery Validate - List of Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, validation

This may be a very stupid question but i am looking for a list of the inline validation rules for the jquery form validator.

I know that i can find the [js functions here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#List_of_built-in_Validation_methods):

but i am looking for a list of the simple inline classes like

email, url, phone, etc., and learn how to use them.  I am just looking for a simple list.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. The first example in the documentation uses classes to define the rules, but the rest of the documentation makes no additional mention of this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Looking at the source](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/core.js#L1057), I believe these are the only rules that can be used simply by adding classes:

- required
- email
- url
- date
- dateISO
- number
- digits
- creditcard

As for how to use them, just add them into the `class` attribute of your `input`:

```
<input type='text' class='required creditcard' name='credit-card' />
```

You'll have to define other rules in the object you pass to `validate`.

Comment: So is there a way to define these validations in the call but by class not field name?

Comment: @user982853: I'm not sure what you mean--If you want to define rules in the `validate` call you must use field names. Additionally, if you apply the class rules to elements, they must have a `name` to be validated correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Most probably you are looking for this

http://elegantcode.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/Jquery-Validator-Cheat-sheet.pdf

Founded when I was looking for same easy to remember list of validation plugin rules. :)

Update: If you like to have all things together try this too:

http://marketblog.envato.com/resources/extensive-collection-cheatsheets-web-designers

Comment: Been looking for a list like this one for the last 2 days. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I can help other people. I also received help here. Cheers!